# DatabaseException(no such table: login)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have that error says:

E/SQLiteLog(16499): (1) no such table: login in "INSERT INTO login (id, name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

and there is image of that error below and I don't no how to solve this I searched for that and I get nothing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA73i.png)

Here is my code:

Sign in page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/home_page.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final formKey2 = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sign in'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: formKey2,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                 controller: _emailController,
                validator: (String? val) {
                  if (val!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Email is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                maxLength: 30,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Email",
                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                 controller: _passwordController,
                validator: (String? val) {
                  if (val!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Password is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                maxLength: 30,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Password",
                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Sign in',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 21,
                  )),
              onPressed: () async {
                if(formKey2.currentState!.validate()){
                  DatabaseHelper.instance.checkUserLogin(_emailController.text,
                      _passwordController.text).then((result){
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                HomePage()));
                  }
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Database:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'Model/users.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {

  static final _dbName = 'UsersData.db';
  static final _dbVersion = 1;
  static final _table = 'Users';
  static final _logInTable = 'login';
  final columnId = 'id';
  final columnName = 'name';
  final columnEmail = 'email';
  final columnPassword = 'password';

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initiateDatabase();

    return _database!;
  }

  _initiateDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        '''
     CREATE TABLE "$_table" (
      "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      "name" VARCHAR2(30),
      "email" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
      "password" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE "$_logInTable" (
    "name" VARCHAR2(30),
      "email" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
      "password" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
    );
      ''');
  }


  Future <List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAll() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(_table); }


  Future<int> insert(Users users) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(_table, users.toMap());
  }

  Future checkUserLogin(String email, String password) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var res = await  db.rawQuery("select * from $_table where email = '$email' and password = '$password'");
    if(res.length>0) {
      List list =
      res.map((c) => Users.fromMap(c)).toList();
      await db.insert("$_logInTable",list[0].toMap());
      return list[0];
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future getUser() async{
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var logInTable = await  db.rawQuery("select * from $_logInTable");
    if(logInTable == null)
      return 0;
    return logInTable.length;
  }

  Future<int> update(Users users) async{
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.update('$_table', users.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [users.id]);
  }

  Future<int> delete (int id) async{
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await
    db.delete(_table, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

}
```

Comment: try to change `"$_loginTable"` to `$_loginTable` in table create

Comment: It doesn't work I tried also (_loginTable)

Comment: its quite roundabout, but, why don't you try `CREATE TABLE login` directly instead of using variable?